# Bash function find and rm

Tags: bash, recursion

I am trying to do a recursive grep and deleting files with less than a specified entry.

To be more clear, I have a directory of 400000 text files and in each file i have 10 items each starting with the `>`. Now the problem is that some of the files out of the 4000000 files have only 6-7 or 8-9 items starting with `>`.

So I wish to delete the files which have fewer than 10 items. I am using the recursive function, however i am not able to figure out how to add `rm` in the recursive way. What I have till now is:

```
find . -name "*.[txt]" -exec grep ">" -c {} \;
```

Comment: `*.[txt]` looks for files with names ending in either `.t` or `.x`. I imagine that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-exec` like this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c '(( $(grep ">" -c "$1") <= 10 )) && rm "$1"' - '{}' \;
```

To avoid creating shell per file you can use:

```
while read -r f; do
    (( $(grep ">" -c "$f") <= 10 )) && rm "$f"
done < <(find . -name "*.txt")
```

Comment: `[[ $(...) -le 10 ]]`? If you have a shell that supports `[[ ... ]]`, you can do `(( $(...) <= 10 ))`, and have a much cleaner syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I agree `<=` could have been used here. (Edited)

Comment: err, not with `[[ ]]` but with `(( ))`; with `[[ ]]` it's a lexical comparison, so, for instance, `[[ 2 >= 10 ]]` (using lexical sorting rules), but `(( 2 < 10 ))` (using numeric rules).

Comment: Oh Yes completely overlooked that in hurry.

Comment: Good deal; +1. Only change I might still make would be putting a `while (( $# )); do ...; shift; done` around the whole thing and using `-exec ... {} +` for efficiency, to invoke the shell once per ARG_MAX rather than once-per-file.

Comment: Yes I agree that will be more efficient. I will edit it in a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into smaller steps:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -c '>' {} + | 
awk -F: '$2 != 10 {print $1}' | 
xargs echo rm
```

remove the "echo" if you're satisfied it's working

The awk step is fragile if you have any filenames containing ":"